# Improving select speed - mysql - very large tables

Tags: mysql, query-performance, large-data-volumes

Newbie to MySQL and SQL in general - so please be gentle :-)

I have a table with a very high number of rows.  The table is:

```
create table iostat (
pkey     int not null auto_increment,
serverid int not null,
datestr  char(15) default 'NULL',
esttime  int not null default 0,

rs       float not null default 0.0,
ws       float not null default 0.0,
krs      float not null default 0.0,
kws      float not null default 0.0,
wait     float not null default 0.0,
actv     float not null default 0.0,
wsvct    float not null default 0.0,
asvct    float not null default 0.0,
pctw     int not null default 0,
pctb     int not null default 0,
device   varchar(50),
avgread  float not null default 0.0,
avgwrit  float not null default 0.0,

primary key (pkey),

index i_serverid (serverid),
index i_esttime (esttime),
index i_datestr (datestr),
index i_rs (rs),
index i_ws (ws),
index i_krs (krs),
index i_kws (kws),
index i_wait (wait),
index i_actv (actv),
index i_wsvct (wsvct),
index i_asvct (asvct),
index i_pctb (pctb),
index i_device (device),
index i_servdate (serverid, datestr),
index i_servest (serverid, esttime)

)
engine = MyISAM
data directory = '${IOSTATdatadir}'
index directory = '${IOSTATindexdir}'
;
```

Right now the table has 834,317,203 rows.

Yes - I need all the data.  The highest level organization of the data is by the collection date (datestr).  It is a CHAR instead of a date to preserve the specific date format I use for the various load, extract, and analysis scripts.

Each day adds about 16,000,000 rows.

One of the operations I would like to speed up is (Limit is generally 50 but ranges from 10 to 250):

```
create table TMP_TopLUNsKRead
  select
    krs, device, datestr, esttime
  from
    iostat
  where
    ${WHERECLAUSE}
  order by
    krs desc limit ${Limit};
```

WHERECLAUSE is:

```
serverid = 29 and esttime between X and Y and device like '%t%'
```

where X and Y are timestamps spanning anywhere from 4 minutes to 24 hours.

I'd prefer to not change the DB engine.  This lets me put data and indexes on separate drives which gave me significant overall performance.  It's also a total of 1.6 billion rows, which would take an insane amount of time to reload.

Comment: What result do you get if you add EXPLAIN to the beginning of this query?

Comment: The element with the highest performance impact in your query is `${WHERECLAUSE}`, it would be useful to show us what that variable is set to.

Comment: I knew I was going to forget that:  serverid = 29 and esttime between X and Y and device like '%t%'   --    X and Y are timestamps that span anywhere from 4 minutes to 24 hours.

Comment: | id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys                             | key   | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | iostat | index | i_serverid,i_esttime,i_servdate,i_servest | i_krs | 4       | NULL | 69421 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------+---------+------+-------+-------------+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
device like '%t%'
```

This is the killer. The leading `%` means it is a search of the whole column, or index if it's indexed, not an index lookup. See if you can do without the leading `%`.

Comment: I was afraid of this.  The data is of the format cXtYYYYYYY...  where X can vary and is not predictable.  The real fix is to add a device_type field.  The presence of the "t" distinguishes between 2 types of device data.

Comment: @opsdog, with a gigarow table designing the schema to be searchable is vital. You might even consider switching to a different RDMS, like PostgreSQL, that offers function indexes and descending indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what's in your `${WHERECLAUSE}` it's impossible to help you.  You are correct that this is a huge table.

But here is an observation that might help: A compound covering index on

```
(krs, device, datestr, esttime)
```

might speed up the ordering and extraction of your subset of data.

Comment: I had put in several compound covering indexes based on specific operations like this one but took them out as the load time for new data became outrageous.

I probably will put this one back in - currently building this temp table (and 2 others just like it) is the slowest recurring task I do against this table.

Comment: And now that I re-read and fully understand your comment...  I might do that, but I don't have any issues with the extract performance from the TMP_... tables.  They are generally a very small subset of the iostat table.